# CSS three column layout issue

Tags: css

```
#left_column {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   padding: 5px;
  width: 20em;
}

#main_content {

  margin-left:  25em;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30em;
}

#right_column {
 margin-left: 60em;
 width: 7em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

I am trying to get three vertical columns on my page here.  The horizontal positioning is the way I want it to be, but I am having some trouble with the vertical alignment.  For some reason the right_column is getting pushed below the main_content column.  I would like to have all columns start at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The reason #right_column is appearing below #left_column and #main_content is because you are not floating the #main_content or the #right_column.

#main_content and #right_column are still part of the normal flow of the html document. This mean they will appear below one another.

If you want all 3 areas to be next to each other you can float the #main_content and #right_column left and reduce/remove the margin-left

Answer (score 0):

Float right column to right. If you don't specify floating, it will be pushed down.

```
#right_column {
 margin-left: 60em;
 width: 7em;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px;
 float:right;
}
```

Also, try decreasing the width of the main content area to see if right column jumps back beside it.

Comment: When I add float:right it is pushing the column to the far right of the container but the column still remains under the main column.

Comment: Alright so the margin-left was the issue.  The float command worked after removing the margin-left line.

Comment: @guy: that is great news then, and yes you needed to modify the margin-left after adding float right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float:right;` to your #right_column

Answer (score 0):

Put These Lines:

```
//Left:
float:left;

//MAIN:
margin-left: 20em; //these will define the width
margin-right: 20em;

//Right:
float:right;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at this [page](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=ThreeColumnLayouts) as well. There are many of examples.